# How to close all connections to the MongoDB server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using [Node MongoDB native driver](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native) to connect to MongoDB database:

```
// Open a connection
db.open(function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});

// Open another connection
db.open(function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});
```

I saw two connection accepted in `mongodb.log` file, but only one end connection. And the program did not exit, I think it's still waiting for the second connection to be closed. How do you close all connections?

Comment: Probably there's another reason why the program didn't exit.

Comment: That's all the codes in the testing program. That's really quick response btw.

Comment: Can you add some debugging output before the close calls to see if the callback gets called?

Comment: Added some debugging output before and after callbacks: https://gist.github.com/1598987

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding your variable `db` with your callback parameter.

Try this instead.

```
// Open a connection
db.open(function (err, p_db) {
  db.close();
}); 

// Open another connection
db.open(function (err, p_db) {
  db.close();
});
```

**Update:** Ok, I guess I was confused about the parameters in the callback, sorry.
Your problem (from the gist), is because you are executing two db.opens with the same db object before you're closing them. Also, it looks like you need separate server objects unless you do things in sequence.

So, what you could do, instead, if you wanted to guarantee it in sequence, is (also, the version of mongodb I have doesn't seem to have the _serverState defined, so I changed it to connected):

```
console.log('[1]', db.serverConfig.connected);
db.open(function (err, db) {
  console.log('[2]', err, db.serverConfig.connected);
  db.close();
  console.log('[3]', err, db.serverConfig.connected);

  console.log('[4]', db.serverConfig.connected);
  db.open(function (err, db) {
    console.log('[5]', err, db.serverConfig.connected);
    db.close();
    console.log('[6]', err, db.serverConfig.connected);
  });
});
```

Which prints:

```
[1] false
[2] null true
[3] null false
[4] false
[5] null true
[6] null false
```

Alternatively, you could define two db variables--but you also need to define two server variables, or it hangs after the first one closes. Like so:

```
var mongodb  = require('mongodb')
  , server   = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {})
  , server2   = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {})
  , db       = new mongodb.Db('test', server, {})
  , db2       = new mongodb.Db('test', server2, {})
  ;

console.log('[1]', db.serverConfig.connected);
db.open(function (err, db) {
  console.log('[2]', err, db.serverConfig.connected);
  db.close();
  console.log('[3]', err, db.serverConfig.connected);
});

console.log('[4]', db2.serverConfig.connected);
db2.open(function (err, db2) {
  console.log('[5]', err, db2.serverConfig.connected);
  db2.close();
  console.log('[6]', err, db2.serverConfig.connected);
});
```

Which prints (for me, and I guess you can't count on the order of 1,4,2,3...):

```
[1] false
[4] false
[2] null true
[3] null false
[5] null true
[6] null false
```

Comment: thx, but the same outcome. `db` and `p_db` are referencing the same object within the callbacks. So, using `db` within the function is not hiding the one outside of it.

Comment: actually, usually the parameter is the collection object, not the db object. I'll test on my own system. Hang on.

Comment: Thanks, both versions work. Now I'm wondering the way I did it, why the second `db.open` does not prevent me from making a connection, since the same db object is trying to connect to the same server from the first `db.open`. Another question is that if a db object has multiple connections, should `db.close` close them all?

Comment: I don't think it should open multiple connections in the first place--might be worth reporting as a bug either way.